# executable jar + audioclips

Tags: eclipse, javafx-8, executable-jar, audioclip

I've been getting this exception when running the app from an executable jar:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported protocol "rsrc"
       at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:233)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.<init>(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:53)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaAudioClip.load(NativeMediaAudioClip.java:63)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.AudioClipProvider.load(AudioClipProvider.java:66)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.AudioClip.load(AudioClip.java:135)
    at javafx.scene.media.AudioClip.<init>(AudioClip.java:83)
    at com.aqua.snakesandladders.view.gamepieces.Token.<init>(Token.java:70)"
```

here's Token.java:70, which is the cause of this:

```
AudioClip bounceSound = new AudioClip(getClass().getResource("/sounds/bounce.wav").toExternalForm());
```

"bounce.wav" is located in "resources" source folder @ "sounds" subfolder.

Running the app in eclipse throws no exception @ this point + plays the AudioClip when needed.

Help! :(

Comment: Have you checked what `getClass().getResource("/sounds/bounce.wav").toExternalForm()` produces? Maybe it is something that the constructor does not like. ( thats what `javafx.scene.media.AudioClip.<init>(AudioClip.java:83)` says)

Comment: it likes it when i run it in eclipse, but not when i run it from the executable jar?

Comment: same syntax gives no issues on both IDE & jar when it comes to images or css files.

Comment: Can you provide some mcve for this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

#### Source

The following is the code that throws Exception:

```
this.scheme = this.scheme.toLowerCase();
if (this.scheme.equals("jar")) {
  URI subURI = new URI(this.uriString.substring(4));
  this.protocol = subURI.getScheme();
  if (this.protocol == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("uri.getScheme() == null!");
  }

  this.protocol = this.protocol.toLowerCase();
} else {
  this.protocol = this.scheme;
}

if (!this.protocol.equals("file") && !this.protocol.equals("http")) {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported protocol \"" + this.protocol + "\"");
} else {
  if (this.protocol.equals("http")) {
    this.canBlock = true;
  }

  this.uri = uri;
}
```

If you print your uri here you can see something like:

```
rsrc:foo.bar.Main
```

Which is a invalid uri as javafx told you.

#### Manifest

So why you uri is invlaid?

If you open your Manifest file, you will find some entries which eclipse added, like：

```
...
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Rsrc-Main-Class: net.xxx.main.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

and here is where the `rsrc` comes from.

#### Advice

- Update your manifest file to be like original manifest, i.e. remove `rsrc` started entry and change main class to your class;
- Not use eclipse to package your jar, using tools like maven, gradle
- Use Intellij :)